# Ebean Model delete in Play-Framework

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I have been trying to learn Ebean with Play Framework 2.5 for a few days. I can do everything I want except deleting an entity (I don't want to use sql unless it's necessary).
Everytime I try to delete an offer (`myoffer.delete()`), it throws this exception:

```
[RuntimeException: get author on [model.Offer] type[null] threw error.]
```

The offer class is this:

```
@Entity
public class Offer extends Model {

    //Basic Fields
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String title;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String description;


    @Column(nullable = false)
    public Date publishDate;

    public Date startDate;

    public Date finishDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public boolean sold;

    //Relations
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public User author;

    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public OfferCategory category;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="offers")
    public List<Image> images;

    //Finder
    public static Finder<Long, Offer> find = new Finder<>(Offer.class);

    @PreRemove
    protected void preRemove() {
        for(Image img:this.images){
            img.offers.remove(this);
        }
        this.author.offers.remove(this);
    }
    //Constructors
    public Offer(){}
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

#### Edit 1:

In this case, and because the delete method its going to be used very little, I am using pure sql queries. I know the method performance might not be the best, but at least it's working:

```
@Override
public void delete(Long... idsLongArray) {
    StringBuilder deleteImages = new StringBuilder("DELETE FROM image_offer WHERE offer_id IN (?)");
    StringBuilder deleteOffer = new StringBuilder("DELETE FROM offer WHERE id IN (?)");
    int j;
    int k;
    for (int i = 1; i < idsLongArray.length; i++) {
        j = deleteImages.lastIndexOf("?");
        k = deleteOffer.lastIndexOf("?");
        deleteImages.replace(j, j + 1, "?,?");
        deleteOffer.replace(k, k + 1, "?,?");
    }
    SqlUpdate imgQuery = Ebean.createSqlUpdate(deleteImages.toString());
    SqlUpdate offerQuery = Ebean.createSqlUpdate(deleteOffer.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < idsLongArray.length; i++) {
        imgQuery.setParameter(i + 1, idsLongArray[i]);
        offerQuery.setParameter(i + 1, idsLongArray[i]);
    }
    imgQuery.execute();
    offerQuery.execute();

    /*List<Offer> offers = Offer.find.select("id").where().in("id", idsLongArray).findList();
    for(Offer offer: offers){
        offer.save();
        offer.delete();
    }*/
}
```

#### Edit2:

Using the advices that @Salem told me in the comments, we made it work. I just had to remove the `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` params from the many to one relations.

```
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
@ManyToOne
public User author;

@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
@ManyToOne
public OfferCategory category;
```

Also my final delete method looks like this:

```
public void delete(Long... idsLongArray) {
    for(Long id: idsLongArray){
        Offer.find.byId(id).delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: From here it looks like it is trying to load the associated user (with shouldn't be null) and delete it, but is getting null. Have you sure this offer as an associated user in the database?

Comment: @Salem Yeah, if I load the offer I can display all the values. In fact, I'am doing that in the web page before deleting it. 
As I put in the Edit1 code, I only want to delete the offer, and the entry in the many to many relation table with images. In the last commented part of the code you can see the last attempt I did before using SQL.
Thanks btw.

Comment: So you can load the user associated to the offer? that's odd. Try to remove the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in the ManyToOne annotation of User

Comment: @Salem That worked! Thank you!. Im going to edit the question to show my final code.